# Arduino IDE equivalent to DataView?

Tags: arduino-ide, bluetooth, buffer

I am working on a project with Bluetooth commands between various devices. I would like to try and convert a string to a DataView Object on Arduino, so I can send it over BLE, much like this function written in Javascript:

```
function str2DV(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  var DV = new DataView(buf);
  return DV;
}
```

Is this possible with Arduino? I have yet to find a solution....

Comment: Have you seen this library? https://github.com/bakercp/BufferUtils

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no use for a DataView in the Arduino environment. In the
JavaScript language, a string and an array of bytes are two very
different things. That's why you need something like this `str2DV()`
function to convert between them. In C++, they are one and the same
thing: no need to convert. Sometimes the type `uint8_t` (also named
`byte`) is used in preference of `char` for storing binary data, but you
can just typecast between these types. The typecast typically compiles
to zero machine instructions, as the underlying data representation is
the same.

For example:

```cpp
extern some_lib_function(const uint8_t *buffer, int buffer_length);

const char *my_message = "Hello, World!\n";
some_lib_function((uint8_t *) my_message, strlen(my_message));
```

If your string is in the form of a `String` object, rather than a plain
C-string, then use the `c_str()` method to get the plain string back:

```cpp
String my_message = "Hello, World!\n";
some_lib_function((uint8_t *) my_message.c_str(), my_message.length());
```